# Performance nested exists vs cross apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I was wondering if the nesting of *exists joins* and/or the amount of data in a table can affect performance compared to *cross apply*? I've been trying to pay attention to joins for a while now and I never noticed an extreme amount of difference between using exists or cross apply in Axapta. In almost all my cases I tested the exists joins are a couple of ms faster.

Are there cases where I would want to avoid using exist joins in Axapta?

Example X++ statements, which provide the same result, and their 'translated' SQL queries:

```
SELECT FirstOnly FROM A
EXISTS JOIN B
    WHERE B.RefRecId == A.RecId
EXISTS JOIN C
    WHERE C.RefRecId == B.RecId;

SELECT TOP 1 T1.* 
FROM TableA T1
WHERE T1.DataAreaId = ?
    AND T1.Partition = ?
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 'x'
        FROM TableB T2
        WHERE T2.Partition = ?
        AND T2.DataAreaId = ?
        AND T2.RefRecId = T1.RecId
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT TOP 'x'
            FROM TableC T3
            WHERE T3.Partition = ?
            AND T3.DataAreaId = ?
            AND T3.RefRecId = T2.RecId
            )
        )
```

VS

```
SELECT FirstOnly FROM A
JOIN RecId from B
    WHERE B.RefRecId == A.RecId
JOIN RecId from C
    WHERE C.RefRecId == B.RecId;

SELECT TOP 1 T1.*, T2.RecId, T2.Partition, T2.DataAreaId, T3.RecId, T3.Partition, T3.DataAreaId
FROM TableA T1
CROSS APPLY TableB T2
CROSS APPLY TableC T3
WHERE T1.Partition = ? 
AND T1.DataAreaId = ?
AND T2.RefRecId = T1.RecId
AND T2.PARTITION = ?
AND T2.DataAreaId = ?
AND T3.RefRecId = T2.RecId
AND T3.PARTITION = ?
AND T3.DataAreaId = ?
```

Comment: Compare executions plans and times.

Comment: I have compared the plans for different queries which I found from tracing the DB and the result vary. I'm looking for concrete query constuctions where I would want to avoid exist joins.

Comment: I typically avoid exists joins and replace them with regular join (inner join)  as long as you can guarantee 0 or 1 records on that join, otherwise your result set row count will change, in this case exists join are needed